# How to show divs in order?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a website just for myself, and want to make divs with text appear in order (some interval between appearance will be great) after the page will load. I don't need any special animation.

I tried to find something on Stack Overflow or anywhere else, but I couldn't. It should be some kind of "copy" of messenger.

Here is what I got:

```html
<div class="messages-area">
  <div class="message bubbledLeft">
    <p>Hey!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message bubbledLeft last-bubbled-left">
    <p>Did you hear about it?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message bubbledRight last-bubbled-right">
    <p>Huh? About what?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message bubbledLeft">
    <p>About this new website!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2p860Lxt

Comment: look up css animations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could first hide them with CSS (for instance with `display: none` in the `.message` class), and then use the promise returned by `.delay().promise()` to show them with delay, and chain those promises with `reduce`:

```js
$(".message").get().reduce(function (acc, div) {
    return acc.then(function () {
        return $(div).show().delay(400).promise();
    });
}, $.when()); // start with a resolved promise
```

```css
.message { display: none };
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="messages-area">
  <div class="message bubbledLeft">
    <p>Hey!</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message bubbledLeft last-bubbled-left">
    <p>Did you hear about it?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message bubbledRight last-bubbled-right">
    <p>Huh? About what?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="message bubbledLeft">
    <p>About this new website!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for this. Here's how you could do it with plain JavaScript:

HTML:

```
<div id="message-area"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
function addMessage() {
    var container = document.getElementById("message-area");
    var messageElem = document.createElement("div");
    messageElem.setAttribute("class", "message-area__message");
    messageElem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("my message"));
    container.appendChild(messageElem);
}

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    console.log('loaded')
    for (var i=0; i<5; i++) {
      window.setTimeout(addMessage, 500*i);
    }
});
```

This will add 5 message elements into the message area, 500 milliseconds apart.